# Setup access point on wlan0 and static ip for eth0 on RPi 4

Tags: pi-4, ethernet, access-point

On the one hand, I'd like to create an access point from RPi, without internet, because it's just to be able to connect remotely via ssh.
On the other hand, I'd like to be able to connect an ethernet device to it to be able to communicate with it. But this device requires me to set the ip address of the computer (RPi) to the same network subnet as the ip address of this device (device ip: 192.168.1.100, so for example RPi ip: 192.168.1.50) and set the subnet mask of the computer to 255.255.255.0.

Here is the current configuration :

**Hostaspd configuration :**

`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=RPiHotSpot
hw_mode=g
channel=6
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=1234567890
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

`/etc/default/hostapd`

```
DAEMON_CONF="/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf"
```

**DNSmasq configuration :**

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
interface=wlan0
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.50.150,192.168.50.200,255.255.255.0,12h
```

**Interfaces File :**

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d*
```

**DHCPCD.conf :**

`/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
interface wlan0
nohook wpa_supplicant
static ip_address=192.168.50.10/24
static routers=192.168.50.1

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.1.50/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

I have two problem :

If the device is connected via ethernet, the ssh connection to the RPi becomes impossible.

And if I access the RPi directly, the device is not visible on the ethernet (`ip r` doesn't show me `eth0`).

Thanks for your help.

Hugo.

Comment: What OS are you using? What you have listed is a hodgepodge which is unlikely to work. You can't expect 2 interfaces on different network segments to have the same address.

Comment: @Milliways i'm using raspberry pi os

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm using raspbian 11 bullseye

Comment: Now that you have specified OS (which belongs in your Question) there is a chance what you have  using `dhcpcd` should work. (It looks OK but I don't use hostapd)

You now need to do some diagnostics; run `ip a && ip r` (which is minimal information required for any networking problem).

Then list commands you entered and any error messages.